# HDD life span when lightly used

Tags: hard-drive

We have a 6TB HDD(external) which is used to store files which are very rarely used.

This HDD now contains 5 TB of data. I googled about HDD life span and it appears that HDD life is something  between 3-5 Years.

I want to know considering the fact that we very rarely access this HDD, should we expect a much longer life span?

Above link is not the answer to my question: I want to see if NOT using HDD will increase its life considerably.

Comment: See this post: https://www.backblaze.com/blog/how-long-do-disk-drives-last/ . HDD, like many other products actually, have 3 different types of failing: 1) early failing because of factory defect, 2) random failing all over the time, 3) late failing because of wear-out. Wear-out for a HDD is tighly linked to the workload. The 3-5 years lifespan is typically for a high workload (disks that operate 10 hours/day, or continuously in a server), but for a disk that is only used from time to time it can be much longer.

Comment: @PierU Very nice!

Comment: Its no different than asking, "How long will a car last?"  The answer is: It depends.

Comment: If it's important data, then you shouldn't take any chances. You need a backup.